# Cascade delete with EF Core and C# (excludes business and thus delete address together)

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

My class `Address`:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Complement { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Business> Business { get; set; }
}
```

My class `Business`:

```
public class Business
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string SocialReson { get; set; }
    public string FantasyName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string MainImage { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessPhotos> BusinessPhotos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OpeningHours> OpeningHours { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SocialMedia> SocialMedias { get; set; }
}
```

My `Delete` method:

```
public async Task Delete(int id)
{
    var business = await _context
                             .Business
                             .Include(x => x.Address)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        
    if (business == null)
        return;

    _context.Business.Remove(business);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Even if I leave the FK `AddressId` as `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`, I can't delete the address together.

I'm using .NET 6 and SQL Server.

Comment: What does your modelBinder configuration look like for your dbContext? My guess is that you need to explicitly define the cascade delete.

Comment: In Business entity configuration this is the builder:
builder.HasOne(e => e.Address)
                 .WithMany(x => x.Business)
                 .HasForeignKey(e => e.AddressId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

Comment: @MICHELBALARINCLARO Please go through this link https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx